# Blocked Request by browser with mixed content with html frame and apache reversed proxy?

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy, nexus, mod-proxy

I am running a web app (Nexus of Sonatype) behind a apache reversed proxy as:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost Off
ProxyPass /nexus http://127.0.0.1:8081/nexus
ProxyPassReverse /nexus http://127.0.0.1:8081/nexus
```

The web page uses a few frames to show the nexus web site (just an admin site):

```
<frameset>
   <frame src="quickMenu.html" />
   <frame src="../nexus" />
</frameset>
```

When loading this web page, it tells me that it's blocking the ../nexus link as it's loaded through http, while the web site is loaded through https:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://dev.bla.nl/apps/nexusFrame.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://dev.bla.nl/nexus/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I don't understand this error as the page is loaded as https page and the nexus site is included as relative path.

If I open the page https://dev.bla.nl/nexus directly, it works just fine :(
I played with the reversed proxy settings like the ProxyRequests/ProxyPreserveHost, but without luck.
Any idea how to solve this ?

Note: before the Nexus app was running in a Tomcat container, and I used Ajp as proxy channel, that worked fine, namely:

```
ProxyPass /nexus ajp://127.0.0.1:8080/nexus
ProxyPassReverse /nexus ajp://127.0.0.1:8080/nexus
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use simple proxying and not embedding Nexus in a frame. Details on how to configure this can be [found in the documentation.](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/install-sect-proxy.html)

Comment: What is the difference between my proxying and what you suggest as described in the link you provide? And why not use a frame?

Comment: One difference is that the setup in the documentation has been tested, while yours has not. :-)  If you encounter problems with your non-standard setup it is unlikely we will consider fixing them.  Also see the X-Forwarded-Proto header in the doc link referenced above, you will need that since you are proxying from https to http.

Comment: Ahhhh, I must have been stressing, as I missed the Forward-Proto header... Completely missed it. Just added it and it works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add an incoming request header as `x-forwarded-proto: https` via your reverse proxy configuration
This should resolve the mixed content issue as Nexus will request all resources via https protocol instead of http